# Incorporate TTF file in C

Tags: glcd, stm32f3

I have migrated from a 16x2 alpha-numeric display to a 128x64 graphical in existing project. With that in mind, I am planning on using a larger font instead of the "easy" 5x7. How do I integrate TTF font file in C?? How to generate hex for the same?

Comment: Have you tried using your toolchain's tool for converting binary files into object code?

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: I have used [MuGUI](http://www.mugui.de/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

TTF is a vector font format, you first need to convert it into a bitmap with 1 bit color depth, then load it as an array in your code.

GIMP can save the bitmap as a C array.

Comment: Unless the rest of your C code includes a TTF renderer.

Comment: Good luck doing that on a low resolution LCD, probably with a small (<256KB RAM) fixed point only MCU...